# "ansible" provisioner in packer is failing - "Could not resolve hostname"

Tags: ssh, ansible, packer

[image]

[Git repository URL](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible)

As can see in the code, I'm using same name for *instance_name* in
[gcp_image_packer.json](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible/blob/main/gcp_image_packer.json) and hostname in [hosts](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible/blob/main/playbook/hosts) file.

The GCE instance which I'm running the [gcp_image_packer.json](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible/blob/main/gcp_image_packer.json) on, has all the API access.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4586921/ravichandran suggested a workaround:

Removed *instance_name* and *inventory_file* parameters from  [gcp_image_packer.json](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible/blob/main/gcp_image_packer.json)

And changed *hosts* value  to **all** in [sample_playbook.yml](https://github.com/sagar-aj7/packer-ansible/blob/main/playbook/sample_playbook.yml)